# Is there a way to add two-way ANOVA post hoc comparisons to ggpubr grouped boxplot in R Studio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I am graphing data (DV: MHCII_Iba1_avg) with a 2-factor experimental design (Age: Old, Adult; Group: CON, EtOH T0, EtOH T2, EtOH T7). I want to visualize the significant p-values of a two-way ANOVA with post hoc comparisons onto a grouped boxplot with individual data points. I created a data table with my p-values, and tried using the ggpubr function stat_pvalue_manual() to add significance symbols to the graph. However, group1 and group2 of that data table combine the two factors (Age and Group), so they do not map onto the boxplots (in which `x=Age`, `fill=Group`). Is there a way to make the boxplot function agree with the posthoc comparisons?

Initially I had `fill=Group` as a global aesthetic in ggplot but that gave the following error message

> Error:
> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
> Caused by error in `FUN()`:
> ! object 'Group' not found

The code below creates a graph with p-values, but the box plots are centered around x-axis labels `x=Age` (`fill=Group`) while the p-values are centered on new x-axis labels (Group_Age).

```r
rstudioapi::versionInfo()

$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘2023.3.0.386’

$long_version
[1] "2023.03.0+386"

$release_name
[1] "Cherry Blossom"
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

easy_data <- structure(list(subject = c(
  "35", "36", "15", "16", "23", "24",
  +"3", "4", "21", "22", "5", "6", "25", "26", "2", "8"
), Group = c(
  "CON",
  +"CON", "CON", "CON", "EtOH T0", "EtOH T0", "EtOH T0", "EtOH T0",
  +"EtOH T2", "EtOH T2", "EtOH T2", "EtOH T2", "EtOH T7", "EtOH T7",
  +"EtOH T7", "EtOH T7"
), Age = c(
  "Adult", "Adult", "Old", "Old",
  +"Adult", "Adult", "Old", "Old", "Adult", "Adult", "Old", "Old",
  +"Adult", "Adult", "Old", "Old"
), MHCII_Iba1_avg = c(
  0, 0.666666666666667,
  +2, 1.66666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0,
  +2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3.66666666666667
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  +-16L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

easy_p <- structure(list(.y. = c(
  "MHCII_Iba1_avg", "MHCII_Iba1_avg", "MHCII_Iba1_avg",
  +"MHCII_Iba1_avg"
 ), group1 = c(
  "CON Adult", "EtOH T0 Adult", "EtOH T7 Adult",
  +"EtOH T2 Old"
 ), group2 = c(
  "EtOH T7 Old", "EtOH T7 Old", "EtOH T7 Old",
  +"EtOH T7 Old"
 ), p.value = c(
  0.00306906746657454, 0.0061072829905161,
  +0.00463887526126816, 0.0100000321882928
 ), p.signif = c(
  "**",
  +"**", "**", "*"
 )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  +"tbl", "data.frame"
 ), estName = "estimate", pri.vars = "contrast", adjust = "sidak", side = 0, 
   delta = 0, type = "link", 
   mesg = "P value adjustment: sidak method for 28 tests")

# easy grouped boxplot with individual points and post hoc comparisons
easy_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = MHCII_Iba1_avg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Group),
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = Group),
    stackdir = "center",
    binaxis = "y",
    position = position_dodge(.75),
    binwidth = 0.12,
    stackratio = 0.8
  ) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(easy_p,
    label = "p.signif",
    y.position = 5,
    step.increase = 0.1,
    xmin = "group1",
    xmax = "group2",
    x = NULL,
  )
```

[image: graph]

UPDATE: I reformatted the data to match the 2-factor labels using `mutate()`

I then sorted the labels on the x-axis with `ggplot(aes(x=factor( ., level=c()))`, removed the x-axis tick labels with `scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL)`, added custom text x-axis labels for Age with `annotate()` and `coord_cartesian()`, made the x-axis title a placeholder with `xlab(" ")` and deleted the x-axis ticks with `theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())`

This seems like a messy solution, so if anyone has other ideas please let me know.

```r
easy_data %>%
  mutate(new_categories = paste0(Group, " ", Age)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(new_categories, 
                        level=c('CON Adult', 'EtOH T0 Adult', 'EtOH T2 Adult', 
                                'EtOH T7 Adult', 'CON Old', 'EtOH T0 Old',
                                'EtOH T2 Old', 'EtOH T7 Old')
                        ),
             y = MHCII_Iba1_avg)
         ) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Group),
               alpha = 0.5
               ) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = Group),
               stackdir = "center",
               binaxis = "y",
               position = position_dodge(.75),
               binwidth = 0.12,
               stackratio = 0.8
               ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL) +
  annotate("text", 
           x = 2.5, 
           y = -0.5,
           label = "Adult") + 
  annotate("text", 
           x = 6.5, 
           y = -0.5,
           label = "Old") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,6.5),
                  clip="off") +
  xlab(" ") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(easy_p,
                     label = "p.signif",
                     y.position = 5,
                     step.increase = 0.1,
                     xmin = "group1",
                     xmax = "group2"
                     )
```

[Graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMrar.png)